# How to connect hive with java in ubuntu-eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, hadoop

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:194)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:112)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:105)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:235)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:208)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.<clinit>(TIOStreamTransport.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at com.soniya.demo.KavyaJdb.main(KavyaJdb.java:24)
```

I added the following jars, but it's not working:

- slf4j-nop.jar
- slf4j-simple.jar
- slf4j-log4j12.jar
- slf4j-jdk14.jar

Any One please help me to solve this error?